# Evaluate batch script argument

Tags: windows, batch-file

In python, you can evaluate strings like this:

```
eval("true")
```

which returns a boolean set to `True`

Is there a way to pass an entire command into a batch script argument like this:
`my_script.bat "my_command -do_x=5 do_y=56 ...etc"`

Then have the batch script set that argument in the quotes to a variable:
`set execute_script=%1`

And finally run it? In python we would do:
`eval(execute_script)`

How can I do this in batch script?

Answer (score 0):

```
set "execute_script=%1"
%execute_script%
```

probably.

Comment: Sadly that does not work

Comment: You might need `call %execute_script%` instead, depending on exactly what you're passing

Answer (score 0):

The `eval` function in `python` is very useful indeed, but it has signatures that defines the `eval` function to perform actual evaluations dynamically. That is sadly not something `cmd` has by default. What we can do is to evaluate if a variable is defined, which is not of much use comapred to `eval`.

So creating a variable, evaluating that it is defined then executing it as a macro:

```
@echo off
set "string=%*"
if defined string %string%
```

but that is useless if you simplify it by not creating macros:

```
if not "%1" == "" %*
```